# kerberos authentication fail due time not sync

Tags: kerberos

helloo all my problem happen like this. when trying to login into website cannot logon due to popup message happened showing no referal to server.

checking system event find error mesage identify keberos authentication fail due to that synchtonozing to time is failed.

So how can we prevent from always keberos authentication problem , any reply your can help.

Answer (score 3):

Your text is extremely hard to understand. I have two essential interpretations

- The time is not in sync. Kerberos is very picky about the time being the same on clients and servers because it is an essential part of the authenication process. You just have make sure the time is the same on Kerberos server and clients. Use NTP to achieve this.
- The time failed to sync. In that case, you need to add a lot more information to your post to diagnose that. What OS are you using, how are you trying to sync the time etc.etc.

Comment: its ok we ensure ntp server sync and solving it